# How can I make python download file to current directory of main.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a project on Gitlab that should download files to its current directory (regardless of user OS being Mac/Windows) when the user downloads the repo and uses it on locals. Also, I will read the same file again further in the program.

Can anyone suggest to me what directory name should I pass in the python variable to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Download file to os.getcwd().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download to the same folder as your python file, you can do

```py
from pathlib import Path

dir_to_download_to = Path(__file__).parent
```

If you want to download to the same folder as the user is in, then

```py
import os

dir_to_download_to = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Remember that a user can run a python file from a different folder than the file is in, so you're going to need to decide which of the two is the behaviour you want! The two folders could be different